# Is it normal for android emulator to load more that 7+ minutes?

Tags: android

I tried to run android emulator with Google API 14 and Google API 3 the effect is the same - it loading more than 7+ minutes and seems to be stuck at displaying android logo. But whole this time my CPU is loaded with emulator process. Is it normal? Removing all avd api and reinstalling - will solve the problem?

I can not get it completely loaded. Maybe something wrong while I updated it in Eclipse?

Comment: This is normal for the first time it takes generally 4-5 min but 7+ minutes is little more :O

Comment: I don't know why but the first start of a new AVD was never successful on my computers. I closed the emulator after 10 minutes. The second start was every time much faster.

Comment: I have tried with Pentium 4 processor and it tooks more than 15 min + and I gave up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can happen. If you have eclipse open, try loading the emulator with eclipse closed, and attaching to it later. To avoid this in the future, use the "snapshot" function to allow you to load and save a running image (a bit like hibernation)

Comment: Where can I find "snapshot" function?

Comment: its one of the options (a checkbox) when you create the virtual machine to enable it. Then you need to enable saving of the snapshot when you start the VM itself.

Answer (score 1):

At first time starting of emulator takes some time that is common depends on your PC configuration . don't delete the emulator once you start, just run the project.

Answer (score 0):

The time varies, depending on the configuration of your PC. It spends my old PC(bought 5 years ago) more than 10 minutes launch the emulator of 2.1...